# Buscar e copiar arquivo usando o PowerShell ISE

Tags: powershell

Para copiar os arquivos imagem png de um disco para outro, usamos:

```
Copy-Item "D:\" -Filter "*.png" -Destination "F:\Files_PNG" -Recurse -Force
```

Copia os arquivos e a estrutura de Diretórios.
Quais parâmetros usar para não copiar os Diretórios e Subdiretórios e apenas os arquivos png?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei a solução. Atenção: Se existir arquivos com o mesmo nome, o anterior sera sobrescrito.

```
# Copiaremos os arquivos deste disco
$fonte  = "D:\" 

# Colocamos a data e hora nesta variável 
$agora   = (Get-Date).ToString('MM_dd_yy_HH_mm_ss') 

# Concatenamos o disco de destino com a variável acima para abaixo criarmos o diretório.
$dest    = "$("F:\PNG_")$($agora)" 

# Cria o diretorio de destino
New-Item -ItemType Directory $dest -Force

# Atenção aqui.......CUIDADO: se existir arquivos com o mesmo nome;
# o anterior sera sobrescrito.
# Copiamos apenas os arquivos, (repetindo)
# porem se existir arquivos com o mesmo nome; o anterior sera sobrescrito.
Get-ChildItem $fonte -Filter "*.png" -Recurse -file | Copy-Item -Destination $dest -Force
```